# Django unicode and characters espace

Tags: python, django, unicode-escapes

I'm writing a REST Api using Django and Django REST framework.
I have a profile model which countains several attributes and I'm trying to write an update function for the profile. I have problem with two attributes:

```
attribute1 = models.CharField()
attribute2 = models.IntegerField()
```

In my update function (in `views.py`), I first retrieve the profile that's going to be updated:

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(id=profile_id)
```

then I update the fields using the get function (so that every field that is not in the request remains the same):

```
attribute1 = request.DATA.get('attribute1', profile.attribute1)
attribute2 = request.DATA.get('attribute2', profile.attribute2)
```

The problem I have is that when I create an instance of profile with `attribute1 = "Reg"` and `attribute2 = 1` but when I update another field of the model, `attribute1` becomes `u\"(u\\'Reg\\',)\"` and `attribute2` becomes `u\"'(1,)'`. I don't know where this problem comes from (I have no problem with other fields). Do you have an idea?

Comment: Looks like the values are being `tuple`d and then `repr`ed. Can you post the code for Profile?

Comment: Oh, presume you mean:
`profile.attribute1 = request.DATA...`

Comment: And when do the attributes change, before or after `profile.save()`?